# Why does Devise keep asking me that the name can't be blank?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, authentication, devise

I am new to Rails, and I am working with Devise. The problem I am facing is that my form is not updating the name column of the user when they are signing up. I have the name attribute in the data table, but I can't seem to alter it using a form in devise registration.

```
<h2>Sign up</h2>

<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

  <div><%= f.label :name %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :name, :autofocus => true %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :email %><br />
  <%= f.email_field :email %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :password %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %></div>

  <div><%= f.submit "Sign up" %></div>
<% end %>

<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :encryptable, :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
   has_many :posts

  end
```

Scheme.rb

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20130622203624) do

  create_table "posts", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.text     "description"
    t.integer  "comments_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "title"
  end

  create_table "users", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "name",                                null: false
  end

  add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true, using: :btree
  add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true, using: :btree

  create_table "views", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "email",                              default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     limit: 128, default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",                      default: 0
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  add_index "views", ["email"], name: "index_views_on_email", unique: true, using: :btree
  add_index "views", ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_views_on_reset_password_token", unique: true, using: :btree

end
```

Comment: Did you add the `:name` to the `attr_accessible`? Please copy and paste the `user.rb`.

Comment: done.. I don't think you need or can do attr_accessible in rails 4.

Comment: Can you post the `migration` file that you created to add the `name` column to `user`. If you don't have one there is your problem. If you do, can you post the `schema.rb` user table section.

Comment: http://blog.remarkablelabs.com/2012/12/strong-parameters-rails-4-countdown-to-2013

Comment: I added the schema.rb

Answer (score 2):

If you are using rails4 you need strong parameters. If you need to implement extra parameters to devise, you could either create an additional 1-1 relation called profiles for users and store them there (better in the long run of app or if you have more user data) and I personally feel it to be much easier the incorporating your user data in the devise user table.

Alternatively you could do the following if you are using one or two attributes.

You need to permit the name parameter for devise. in your ApplicationController code, do this.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << :name
   end
end
```

Refer more on this on [devise wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise).

Answer (score 0):

Need to make the following changes - and that should fix it

gem 'protected_attributes'

class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters

def configure_permitted_parameters
 devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) do |u|
  u.permit(:name, :user_type,:email, :password, :password_confirmation)
 end

devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) do |u|
  u.permit(:name,:user_type,:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password)
 end
end