# Validations on extra column in devise not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

#### While inserting some thing in firstName field its show error that firstName should not be blank....

Any Suggestion why this will be happening......?

## Model

members.rb file

```
class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable



  validates :firstName, :presence => true

end
```

## View

new.html.erb file

```
<h2>Sign up</h2>

<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

  <div><%= f.label :firstName %><br />
  <%= f.email_field :firstName, :autofocus => true %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :email %><br />
  <%= f.email_field :email, :autofocus => true %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :password %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %></div>

  <div><%= f.submit "Sign up" %></div>
<% end %>

<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Rails 4, you need to make a list of the parameters you are expecting a form to submit to you. this is called "strong parameters".

Devise has its own way that you can do this, called "sanitizing".

Look up those two terms.

See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20756469/2308190

Comment: Thanks. its work when a comment this line '#protect_from_forgery with: :exception'

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible even you didn't input first name, but in params it still has value as empty string ""? If you use following, could it work？

```
validates :firstName, length: { minimum: 2 }
```

You can chage 2 to any other number.

Comment: while using your answer its still not work its shows again same result       Sign up
1 error prohibited this member from being saved:
Firstname is too short (minimum is 2 characters)

Answer (score 0):

Update your devise view with this.

```
<h2>Sign up</h2>

<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

  <div><%= f.label :firstName %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :firstname, :autofocus => true %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :email %><br />
  <%= f.email_field :email%></div>

  <div><%= f.label :password %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %></div>

  <div><%= f.submit "Sign up" %></div>
<% end %>

<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```

And model

```
validates :firstname, :presence => true
```

Comment: still not working because my db table name field is **firstName** then how it will work will **firstname**